# Distribution of Difference of Independent Inverse Gaussians

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, definite-integrals, normal-distribution

Suppose, $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent inverse Gaussian random variables with parameters $(\mu, \lambda_1)$ and $(\mu, \lambda_2)$, respectively.  (See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Gaussian_distribution) for the notation).

I am interested in the following probability (and whether or not it has a closed form solution):

$$ P(X_1 < X_2) = \int_0^\infty \int_0^y \exp \left(- \frac{\lambda_1(x-\mu)^2}{2\mu^2x} - \frac{\lambda_2(y-\mu)^2}{2\mu^2y} \right) \sqrt{\frac{\lambda_1 \lambda_2}{(2\pi)^2 x^3 y^3}} dx dy$$

$$= \int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{\lambda_2(y-\mu)^2}{2\mu^2y}}\left(\Phi \left(\sqrt{\frac{\lambda_1}{y}}\left(\frac{y}{\mu} -1\right) \right) + e^{2\lambda_1/\mu}\Phi \left(-\sqrt{\frac{\lambda_1}{y}}\left(\frac{y}{\mu} +1\right) \right) \right) \sqrt{\frac{\lambda_2}{2\pi y^3}}dy$$

where $\Phi$ is the [cdf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) (Cumulative distribution function), of a standard normal random variable. I have no idea how to deal with this integral.  The reason I am interested in its closed form is due to the fact that for the case $\mu = 0$, there is a very nice closed form solution relating to the hitting times of two independent Brownian motions ([see here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/286073/2-dimensional-brownian-motion-hitting-time?fbclid=IwAR2YciL8wYdFptdbp3-YehLB5_t2c3Yabl2qgtfx8JUx7SLXvza3CY5ysA0)).

I have tried consulting [this table](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/73B/jresv73Bn1p1_A1b.pdf?fbclid=IwAR0YKs4hti9xezFl1Ds9_D44Z9GfTzDm78tgT2_BHmosHJSEuIgPdQnfMLs) for hints of how to deal with the integral of the [erf function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function), against some other complicated term, to no avail. Any help would be massively appreciated!

Comment: Note that this probability is equal to $\mathsf E(F_{X_1}(X_2))$ which is equal to $1/2$ when $\lambda_1=\lambda_2$.

Comment: Yes, it is obvious that for iid continuous random variables $X_1, X_2$, that $P(X_1 < X_2) = 1/2$.  Assume $\lambda_1 \ne \lambda_2$.